# how to hide and show question when run by mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, input, xampp

I want to have a question that came from database (mysql) and able to answer 1 question at a time..
i was able to call the question but i have no idea on how can i make it a 1 question at a time

Here is the code

`````
      $sql = "SELECT question, answerA,answerB,answerC,answerD, correctAnswer FROM iq_question order by rand() LIMIT 20;";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      ?>

      <div id="first">
        <label class="text-left mt-3" >Please choose the correct answer.</label><br>
        <hr>
        <form method="post" action="" id="form-data">
          <?php

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<center><h4>" .$row["question"]; "</h4></center>";
          echo "<hr>";
          echo "<p class='text-left'>";
          echo "<input type='radio' name='question1ans' id='q1a' value='A'>";
          echo "<label class='text-left' for='Q1A'>A. ".$row["answerA"];"</label></p>";
          echo "<p class='text-left'>";
          echo "<input type='radio' name='question1ans' id='q1b' value='B'>";
          echo "<label for='Q1B'>B. ".$row["answerB"];"</label></p>";
          echo "<p class='text-left'>";


          echo "<input type='radio' name='question1ans' id='q1c' value='C'>";
          echo "<label for='Q1C'>C. ".$row["answerC"];"</label></p>";
          echo "<p class='text-left'>";
          echo "<input type='radio' name='question1ans' id='q1d' value='D'>";
          echo "<label for='Q1D'>D. ".$row["answerD"];"</label></p>";
          echo "<p class='text-left'>";
          echo "<hr>";

          }
        }
          ?> ````
`````

Comment: You would either need Ajax and/or you're looking for "pagination".

Comment: im trying to add pagination , but evertime i change a number it the question changes(rand() in $sql).

Comment: Does your questions table has an ID column? You could get all the 20 random ID's before start the quiz, save them in $_SESSION and go ahead with "pagination".

Comment: no it dont have, does it require to be a primary key because i want to make a ID with a string

Comment: Yes, you need a primary key in order to read the questions and save the user's answers.

Comment: @Triby where should i add/put the $_SESSION ( i really dont know about this sorry.)